# Filter or remove first row based on ifelse statement for repeated values

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, slice

I have a df:

| ID | Age | Measurement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 24.5 |
| 1 | 3 | 25.0 |
| 2 | 0 | 10.0 |
| 2 | 0 | 11.5 |
| 2 | 1 | 23.5 |
| 2 | 2 | 25.5 |
| 3 | 0 | 9.5 |
| 3 | 1 | 20.0 |
| 4 | 0 | 10.5 |
| 4 | 0 | 11.0 |
| 4 | 1 | 23.5 |
| 4 | 2 | 26.5 |
| 4 | 3 | 27.5 |

All I want to do if filter out that first measurement for repeated measurements if the age is 0.

```
df %>%
ifelse(Age == 0, lead(Age) == 0, slice(-1), *Do nothing*)
```

I just do not know how to get around this^

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   group_by(ID, Age) %>%
   slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
   ungroup()
```

Comment: This is really useful, except I have some IDs = NA that I want to keep, but this method wipes them out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using Dan's code (thank you!):

```
df2<- RC_data %>%
  filter(is.na(Age))

df<- df%>%
  filter(!(is.na(Age))) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Age) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()

df<- full_join(df, df2)
```